# SVG disappears in firefox on transform

Tags: javascript, svg, cross-browser, transform, d3.js

In Safari all is well, in Firefox, the svg is not the correct size and when I transform it, it disappears.  I'm running Safari Mac 5.1.7 and Firefox Mac 15.0.

The code was created with d3 but I've just supplied the html.

Now you see it:  http://bl.ocks.org/3531350

Now you don't:  http://bl.ocks.org/3531267 (edited so it works now)

I imagine I have made a foolish mistake somewhere but I just can't see it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see the svg at the bottom of the grey area if I add height and width attributes of 100% to the outer svg element. They do really need to be there if you are using svg embedded in html. I suspect Safari will require width/height in embedded svg at some point.